# Change Slug in URL of Posts of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have custom post type registered with `'has_archive' => 'gallery'`. It works fine when visiting `mysite.com/gallery/` it opens archive-vmgallery.php and it works fine.

However, I would like that vm gallery posts would also have slug 'gallery'. Instead wordpress generates URLs in form `mysite.com/vmgallery/post-slug`, thus 'old' custom post type is used (`vmgallery`) in URL instead of new one (`gallery` or `mysite.com/gallery/post-slug`). How to fix it?

```
$labels = array(
            'name' => __('VmGallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN, THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'singular_name' => __('VmGallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'add_new' => __('Add New', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'new_item' => __('New Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'all_items' => __('All Galleries', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'view_item' => __('View Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'search_items' => __('Search Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'not_found' => __('No galleries found', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No galleries found in the Trash', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'parent_item_colon' => '',
            'menu_name' => __('Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
        );
$supports = array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields', 'post-formats', 'author', 'excerpt');

 $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'description' => 'Galleries specific information',
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 6,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-image',
            'supports' => $supports,
            'taxonomies' => array('gallery_categories', 'post_tag'),
            'has_archive' => 'gallery'
        );

        register_post_type('vmgallery', $args);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't explicitly set a slug, so it uses the post type key you registered it with. To set it to gallery, set `slug` of `rewrite` parameter:

```
$args = array(
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'gallery' ),
    // the rest of your args...
);
register_post_type( 'vmgallery', $args );
```

[See the Codex page for `register_post_type` for a full list of parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).